# How can you make a TextArea's htmlText change, based upon a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textarea, mxml

Let's say you want to use a single label whose text changes in real-time, based on the value of a variable, which is pretty easy to do in AS3.  But let's say you want part of the text to be in regular font-weight, and you want the other part to be in bold.  I'm assuming a TextArea with an htmlText value is necessary, to maintain the bold / not bold parts within the single label, but I don't see how to make the data in there change, based upon a variable, like you can with an ordinary text attribute.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var firstPart:String = "someText";
var boldPart:String = "this is bold";
text.htmlText = firstPart + "<b>" + boldPart + "</b>";
```

You can also use [setTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29) to make only a part of a text in a textfield bold:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.bold = true;
textField.setTextFormat(tf,10,20); // makes chars from 10 to 20 bold
```